# How to zoom out video and add borders on FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Believe it or not I couldn't find this on Google. Basically I'm trying to shrink a video to a smaller size, while keeping the resolution and adding black borders. I'm doing this so that I can watch videos with subtitles on my CRT screen.

Answer (score 0):

Found out I could just lower the resolution using -vf scale, and then add the borders using this Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46693766